# How do you create wireshark dissector subtrees programmatically based on a protocol value?

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

How do you create a Wireshark dissector in C that can parse a protocol to determine the number of sub-trees to create and then programmatically create that number of sub-trees.

I am working with a protocol that has 2 parts

1) the number of requests in the packet (2bytes long )

2) followed by those requests ( 1 to 20 requests each 5 bytes long)

Each request is 5 bytes long

```
 2 bytes - Request number
 3 bytes - random number
```

here is an example packet

```
020155502666
```

This packet dissected is

```
Length : 02
request 01:
random number : 555
request 02:
random number: 666
```

This code allows me to create a master tree with a single sub-tree which I add the request number and random number to. How do I change it to programmatically create a sub tree under the master tree for each request object.

```
dissect_packet (tvbuff_t *tvb, packet_info *pinfo, proto_tree *tree, void *data _U_)
{
/* Set up structures needed to add the protocol subtree and manage it */
proto_item *ti
proto_tree *tree , *tree_sub

/* Other misc. local variables. */
guint offset = 0;
guint16 number_of_requests;


/* create display subtree for the protocol */
ti = proto_tree_add_item(tree, tree, tvb, 0, -1, ENC_NA);
packet_tree = proto_item_add_subtree(ti, tree_sub);



proto_tree_add_item(packet_tree, hf_requestID, tvb, offset, 2, ENC_BIG_ENDIAN);
offset += 2;
proto_tree_add_item(packet_tree, hf_random_number, tvb, offset, 3, ENC_BIG_ENDIAN);
offset +=3;


}
```